# How do i compare two JSONArray in java?

Tags: java, json

How do i compare two JSONArray in such a way that, if any value matches in these two, the function must return `true`.  For example:

```
array1=={1,2,3,4,5,6} 
array2=={9,10,11,1,12}
```

When comparing these two arrays the result is `true` because there is at least one element in common between the two arrays.  Position within the array is not important.

I am trying to compare this through a primitive way (looping through each Array and comparing the value).

```
private boolean compareArrays(JSONArray deviation, JSONArray deviationIds) throws JSONException {
for (int i = 0; i < deviation.length(); i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < deviationIds.length(); j++)
if(deviation.getString(i).equals(deviationIds.getString(j)))
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

This code works, but i want to know if there is a way i could do this much more professionally. Maybe, achieve this by using JAVA Stream API.
Please comment if you need any additional information.
Thanks!!

Comment: What happens if the number of elements in both arrays don't match?

Comment: it will return false..

Comment: Would you please add import for JSONArray?

Comment: @Michal This is my requirement ..If any value matches from both the array the function must return a true value... or else it must return a false.

Comment: Ok. Sorry, I misread your requirement.

Comment: Just to be perfectly clear, say `array1=={1,2,3,4,5,6}` and `array2=={9,10,11,1,12}` you want to return `true`?

Comment: Yes @JimGarrison thats exactly what i want..Thanks!!

Comment: You need intersection of two collections. Do you have possibility to get these JSONArrays into Collection, array or stream? If yes, then producing intersection is easy and non-emnpty intersection translates into returning true from your method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XStream's for handling of JSON mappings

http://x-stream.github.io/json-tutorial.html

Or as per your logic you retrieving string   , You can compare as

```
 JSONCompareResult result = JSONCompare.compareJSON(json1, json2, JSONCompareMode.STRICT);
 System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

The requirement *for any match return true* can be re-formulated as *for non-empty intersection return true*. Converting the `JSONArray` into `Collection` allows for that quite easily, e.g. like this

```
public class JsonArrayIntersectTest {

private boolean anyMatch(JSONArray first, JSONArray second) throws JSONException {
    Set<Object> firstAsSet = convertJSONArrayToSet(first);
    Set<Object> secondIdsAsSet = convertJSONArrayToSet(second);
    //Set<Object> intersection = Sets.intersection(firstAsSet, secondIdsAsSet);         // use this if you have Guava
    Set<Object> intersection = firstAsSet.stream()
            .distinct()
            .filter(secondIdsAsSet::contains)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    return !intersection.isEmpty();
}

Set<Object> convertJSONArrayToSet(JSONArray input) throws JSONException {
    Set<Object> retVal = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        retVal.add(input.get(i));
    }
    return retVal;
}

@Test
public void testCompareArrays() throws JSONException {
    JSONArray deviation = new JSONArray(ImmutableSet.of("1", "2", "3"));
    JSONArray deviationIds = new JSONArray(ImmutableSet.of("3", "4", "5"));

    Assert.assertTrue(anyMatch(deviation, deviationIds));

    deviation = new JSONArray(ImmutableSet.of("1", "2", "3"));
    deviationIds = new JSONArray(ImmutableSet.of("4", "5", "6"));

    Assert.assertFalse(anyMatch(deviation, deviationIds));

    }
}
```

However, that is much more code then the initial version using the `JSONArray` API directly. It also produces much more iteration then the direct `JSONArray` API version, which might or might not be a problem. In general, I would however argue that it is not a good practise to implement domain logic on *transport* types such as `JSONArray` and would always convert into a domain model anyway.

Please also note that production-ready code would additionally do `null` checks on arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to USE JAVA Stream API, the object must be Iterable.
As @Michal mentioned, you can change it to Collection.
From @Michal's answer, we can simplify it, just like:

```
public class JsonArrayIntersectTest {

    private boolean anyMatch(JSONArray first, JSONArray second) throws JSONException {
        Set<Object> firstAsSet = convertJSONArrayToSet(first);
        Set<Object> secondIdsAsSet = convertJSONArrayToSet(second);
        // use stream API anyMatch
        return firstAsSet.stream()
                .anyMatch(secondIdsAsSet::contains);
    }

    private Set<Object> convertJSONArrayToSet(JSONArray input) throws JSONException {
        Set<Object> retVal = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            retVal.add(input.get(i));
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    @Test
    public void testCompareArrays() throws JSONException {
        JSONArray deviation = new JSONArray(ImmutableSet.of("1", "2", "3"));
        JSONArray deviationIds = new JSONArray(ImmutableSet.of("3", "4", "5"));

        Assert.assertTrue(anyMatch(deviation, deviationIds));

        deviation = new JSONArray(ImmutableSet.of("1", "2", "3"));
        deviationIds = new JSONArray(ImmutableSet.of("4", "5", "6"));

        Assert.assertFalse(anyMatch(deviation, deviationIds));

    }
}
```

Comment: Agree - the anyMatch() approach is better then the intersection one.